# Inequality Weight of Cans

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A grocery scale is designed to be accurate to within 0.25oz. If two identical cans of soup placed on the scale have combined weight of 35.15oz, what are the largest and smallest possible weights of one of the cans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scales are accurate to 0.25 oz, and display a weight of 33.15 oz. Therefore the "actual" weight of the two cans is anything between 32.9 oz and 33.4 oz.

The largest possible weight of a single can (given they are identical) is therefore: $\frac{33.4}{2} = 16.7\mbox{ oz}$. The smallest possible weight is $\frac{32.9}{2} = 16.45\mbox{ oz}$.